# Start an Android Instant App from a NFC Tag

Tags: android, nfc, android-instant-apps

I have developped a simple Instant App to demonstrate feature.
When i click on an URL from a mail, the instant app is streamed and seems to work fine. I can then proposed to user to install an app using NFC features.
When I tap a NFC tag containing the same URL, I am redirected to the browser but instant app is not loaded/started.

Is it due to instant app permission restriction (NFC) ?

How can i stream this instant app using an url from Tag ? (already tried something like this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=&launch=true? without succes)

Note: The instant app do not use NFC feature. What i do not unsderstand, is why when taping a tag with url (same as url in mail) nothing append, except the opening of the browser to the URL.

Tks in advance for advises or explanations

BR,Fred.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue as well, when opening the URL on the browser, the instant app is not started.

I think for the instant app to launch, you need to open the URL directly using play store (it worked for me).
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<id_name>&launch=true

Also, you need to enable the [settings](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7240211?hl=en) for allowing instant apps.